Query not returning the correct result
I have a couple of tables where one shows, per record, and ID of a project with the metadata tag of a file. Clients upload multiple files per project ID. When the client uploads a file for a project ID, the file is marked with a tag. Some of those files are mandatory for all project ID's. There is a second table where it stores all the mandatory tags.
Table 1, tags per ID:
ID  Tag
37616   CORE_CCA
37616   CSHOT_FILE
37616   DRILL_DEV
37616   DRILL_EOWR
37616   DWL_WIRE
37616   GEOL_BIO
37616   GEOL_GEOW
37616   GPHYS_CSHOT
37616   GPHYS_GEN
37616   JWL_AUDIT
37616   JWL_FILE
37616   LOG_COMP
37616   LOG_CORE
37616   LOG_LITH
37616   LOG_MUD
37616   LOG_VEL
37616   LOG_WIRE
37616   VSP_SEGY
37616   WDD_FILE

Table 2, Mandatory tags:
Tag
DRILL_DEV
DRILL_EOWR
GEOL_GEOW
GEOL_MUD
LOG_CASE
LOG_COMP
LOG_MUD
PRE_DPROG
PRE_GPROG
WDD_FILE

I am trying to do a join that shows me the result of all the mandatory tags that I am missing in table1. In this specific case, the result should be:
ID  Tag
31716   GEOL_MUD
31716   LOG_CASE
31716   PRE_DPROG
31716   PRE_GPROG
31716   WDD_FILE

I have tried a left join:
select e.ID, e.tag, m.tag
from table2 m left join table1 e on m.tag = e.tag

But that does not give me what I need. I also added a null value in the where clause for e.tag = null but that returns something else. The last thing I tried was the "exists" clause and that does not return what I need either:
select e.id, e.tag
from table1 e 
where exists (select * from table2 where tag = e.tag)

Any ideas?

What would be the correct result?

In SQL comparing with NULL is done through IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

Do a cross join to create all the possible combinations. The do a left join to match the ones actually present (two equality checks in the join condition.)

WDD_FILE is in both sets so therefore shouldn't be on your expected results.

I'd use a cross join to get the required tags for each ID then join back to the table1.
SELECT Z.ID, Z.Tag 
FROM (SELECT distinct T1.ID, T2.Tag
   FROM table1 T1
   CROSS JOIN table2 T2) Z
LEFT JOIN table1 A
 on Z.ID = A.ID
and Z.Tag = A.tag
WHERE A.ID is null

The issue might be if you're looking at doing this for all ID's if ID 2 has the required tag but ID 1 doesn't, the tag requirement is satisfied by ID 2 and thus doens't show up on ID 1.  By requiring the join for each ID, we ensure each paired value is unique and thus each ID must have the required tags.
Example using Postgres:
https://dbfiddle.uk/rz7owCRW
Giving us:
+-------+-----------+
|  id   |    tag    |
+-------+-----------+
| 37616 | GEOL_MUD  |
| 37616 | LOG_CASE  |
| 37616 | PRE_DPROG |
| 37616 | PRE_GPROG |
+-------+-----------+

In this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/tfryHEX9
we added ID 37515 with just LOG_CASE tag filled in.
We can see that 37616 retains log_case using this approach.
If we eliminate the cross join, and thus the join using ID, we can see the LOG_CASE is removed from 37616
https://dbfiddle.uk/xp2FKWYL; and that's because the ID 37515 uses LOG_CASE and we didn't do the cross join to get the unique paired tag values

Try it like this:
--    S Q L :
SELECT      t.ID, m.TAG
FROM        ( Select      t.ID, m.TAG 
              From        tags_per_id t
              Inner Join  mandatory_tags m  ON(t.TAG = m.TAG) 
            ) t
INNER JOIN  mandatory_tags m ON (m.TAG NOT IN(Select TAG From tags_per_id Where ID = t.ID) ) 
GROUP BY    t.ID, m.TAG

/*    R e s u l t :
        ID TAG       
---------- ----------
     37616 GEOL_MUD  
     37616 PRE_DPROG 
     37616 PRE_GPROG 
     37616 LOG_CASE   */

NOTE: you should handle separately if there is ID with none of mandatory tags at all .

I think you should think of it the other way around. You could try something like this:
select t1.id, t2.tag from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.tag=t2.tag

In this example table1 and table2 refer to the names in your question, you could add a where to that query in case you want to add more filtering, when case your schemas will grow.
You might want to add a filter on NULL tags for example:
select t1.id, t2.tag from tags t1 left join mandatory t2 on t1.tag=t2.tag where t2.tag IS NOT NULL

